# Call external API from SharePoint online using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am having HTML file for user input and use REST API for update into SharePoint list.
we have a requirement to get value from external API.

I am able run the below script from normal HTML form, and get the result

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#btn_getEmpID").click(function () {
        // getUserInfo();
        // alert("vg:test ->" + localStorage.getItem("submittedID"));
        debugger;

        $.ajax({
            asynch: false,
            url:"http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                alert("test:SUCCESS");
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                debugger;
                alert(JSON.stringify(x) + '\n' + JSON.stringify(y) + '\n' + JSON.stringify(z));
            }
        });
    });
})
```

while using in SharePoint online, I am getting error.

What would be the best option to access the external API in SharePoint online page?

thanks
GV

Comment: I have used this HTML form as a page in SharePoint to enter input and submit the data into SharePoint list.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If we call this rest api directly,it reports this error.
[image]
Soluation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content
Updated code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {                  
        $.ajax({                
            url:"https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {                    
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {                    
                console.log(error);
            }
        
    });
})  
</script>
```

Test Result:
[image]